# Which project types are not supported by Monodevelop?

Tags: monodevelop, sln-file

When such project is exist in solution file, monodevelop writes: "The project type is not supported by MonoDevelop"

Which project types (by their guids) are not supported in which versions?

The lists of project types (which are supported by different versions of MSVS) are probably provided in MSDN (but how to find their guids?)

http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop has a built-in list of all project types that are either not supported or require an optional addin.

You can find that list [in the source tree](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop) in the file [`MonoDevelop.Core.addin.xml`](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core.addin.xml).

Under `<Extension path = "/MonoDevelop/ProjectModel/UnknownMSBuildProjectTypes">` element you'll find the project types you're looking for. As an example:

```
<ProjectType guid = "{42C0BBD9-55CE-4FC1-8D90-A7348ABAFB23}" name = "Xamarin.Mac" platforms="mac" product = "Xamarin.Mac" />
```

At the time of posting you'll find the real thing [here](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core.addin.xml#L299) but that might change.

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/213671). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: How exactly would copy-pasting the target of the link - which can *change* - add value to this?

Comment: I can imagine my edit adds that value, no problem, my pleasure, glad I could help.